# Reflections getting all methods within a specific class which are annotated

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I am writing an event message handler. To handle the reflection, I am using Reflections API (https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).

Each event listener is a method annotated by

```
public @interface ListenTo {}
```

and a listener would follow a theme such as:

```
class Example {
  EventHandler.get.registerListener(this)

  @ListenTo
  def onEvent(e: SomeEvent): Unit 
}
```

and the code to register the listeners is as follows:

```
import org.reflections.ReflectionUtils._
private var listeners: mutable.ListBuffer[(Any, List[Method])] = ListBuffer()

def registerListener(obj: Any): Unit = {
  listeners += Tuple2(obj, getAllMethods(obj.getClass, withAnnotation(classOf[ListenTo])).asScala.toList)
}
```

However, on registering a listener, the object is saved within the tuple, but no methods with it, does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by doing

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ListenTo
```

For anyone else who comes by this.